# Не сохраняются изменения wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress, scss

При изменении scss в wordress на странице не обновляются данные (translateY) (кеш чистил) [image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Нужно скомпилировать стили после изменения в scss

Comment: Как?) Я просто первый раз вордпресом пользуюсь

Comment: это не зависит от того использовали вы WP или нет. вам нужно установить sass, выкачать все стили и потом перекомпилировать их через команду sass scss/theme.scss:css/theme.css само собой путь к файлам и их названия будут отличатся

Comment: Править нужно css, а не то что ты правишь. И код надо показывать кодом, а не картинками.